# R tweets with emojis

Tags: r, regex, twitter

I scrapped tweets from the twitter API and the package `rtweet` but I don't know how to work with text with emojis because they are in the form '\U0001f600' and all the regex code that I tried failed until now. I can't get anything of it.

For example

```
 text = 'text text. \U0001f600'
 grepl('U',text)
```

Give me FALSE

```
 grepl('000',text)
```

Also give me FALSE.

Another problem is that they are often sticked to the word before (for example `i am here\U0001f600` )

So how can I make R recognize emojis of that format? What can I put in the grepl that will return me TRUE for any emojis of that format?

Comment: There is no `U`, no `000`, see https://ideone.com/LvqDEj. There is ``. What exactly do you want to do with these chars/strings?

Comment: If you want to get rid of these character using rtweet you can use rtweet::plain_tweets(*name of your text column*)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to do many things with them (count them, order them, see which are occuring the most) but first of all I would like to get rid of them because they don't look nice in my wordcloud.

Comment: @HarroCyranka I would like to keep them and to isolate them because I want to study them later

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What is not answerable in my question? I just want to know how to isolate the emoji from the text...

Comment: What do you mean by "isolate"?

Comment: For example if I have a vector of text, I want to be able to split the text with 2 vectors, one with only the text, and one with only the emojis

Comment: @K.Hua Look, regex questions are usually answered in 2-5  minutes. Yours is not because it is not quite clear what your output should look like. Please edit the question to provide exact sample text and expected output for that text.

Comment: Please also state what emoji unicode standard you want to support. I guess [the latest](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will try to make it as simple as possible: What can I put in the grepl function that will return me TRUE for any text with emojis? Given that they all look like '\U000xxxxx'

Comment: There is a problem with testing this out, as when I am entering the string literal as you do, the high surrogate is removed, and the only char that I get is not the grinning face emoji but the `\u0600` char. Try https://ideone.com/QJDp27.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R there tends to be a package for most things. And in this case [`textclean`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textclean/index.html) and with it comes the `lexicon` package which has a lot of dictionaries. Using textclean you have 2 functions you can use, `replace_emoji` and `replace_emoji_identifier`

```
text = c("text text. \U0001f600", "i am here\U0001f600")

# replace emoji with identifier:
textclean::replace_emoji_identifier(text)
[1] "text text. lexiconvygwtlyrpywfarytvfis " "i am here lexiconvygwtlyrpywfarytvfis " 

# replace emoji with text representation
textclean::replace_emoji(text)
[1] "text text. grinning face " "i am here grinning face "
```

Next you could use `sentimentr` to use sentiment scoring on the emoji's or for text analysis `quanteda`. If you just want to check the presence as in your expected output:

```
grepl("lexicon[[:alpha:]]{20}", textclean::replace_emoji_identifier(text))
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use a single character `\` in your code:

```
text = 'text text. \U0001f600'
```

It really should be `\\`:

```
text = 'text text. \\U0001f600'
```

I had a similar experience using the [rtweet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/index.html) library.

In my case the tweets bring some Unicode code points, not just emoji, and with the following format: `"some text<U+code-point>"`. What I did in this case was "convert" that code point to its graphic representation:

```
library(stringi)

#I use gsub() to replace "<U+code-point>" with "\\ucode-point", the appropriate format
# And stri_unescape_unicode() to un-escape all Unicode sequences    
stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("<U\\+(\\S+)>",
                                   "\\\\u\\1", #replace by \\ucode-point
                                   "some text with #COVID<U+30FC>19"))
#[1] "some text with #COVIDー19"
```

If the Unicode code point is not delimited as in my case (<>), you should change the regular expression from `"<U\\+(\\S+)>"` to `"U(\\S+)"` . You should be careful here, because this will work correctly if a space character appears after the code point. In case you have words attached to the code point both before and after, it must be more specific and indicate the number of characters that compose it, example `"U(....)"`.

You can try refining this regular expression using Character Classes, or specifying only hexadecimal digits `"U([A-Fa-f0-9]+)"`.

Note that in the RStudio console, the emoji are not going to be seen, you can apply this function but to see the emoji you must use an R library for this purpose. However other characters can be seen: `"#COVID<U+30FC>19"` appears in the RStudio console as `"#COVIDー19"`.

Edit: Actually `"\\S+"` didn't work for me when there were consecutive Unicode code points like `"<U+0001F926><U+200D><U+2642>"`. In this case it only replaced the first occurrence, I didn't delve into that, I just changed my regular expression to `"<U\\+([A-Fa-f0-9]+)>"`.
`"[A-Fa-f0-9]"` represents hexadecimal digits.